# How to make Highcharts work inside an Electron App?

Tags: javascript, browser, highcharts, electron-builder, uncaught-reference-error

HTML document: `<script src="code/highcharts.js"></script>`

In a renderer js file: `Highcharts.chart('graph', {...});`

The `main.js` looks like this:

```js
win = new electron.BrowserWindow({
  width: config.width,
  height: config.height,
  backgroundColor: "#000000",
  resizable: true,
  show: false,
  useContentSize: true,
  webPreferences: {
    backgroundThrottling: false,
    contextIsolation: false,
    nodeIntegration: true,
    spellcheck: false,
    zoomFactor: desired_zoomfactor,
  }
});
```

I can obviously turn `nodeIntegration` off, this breaks the program though and is not a solution.

The error inside Electron is always the same:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined

Why does it work in a Browser, but not in Electron? There is no need for security in my app. So why is it so difficult to make it work?

I have tried using a preloader (does that even make sense here?), using the cdn source and loading the source inside js.

Answer (score 5):

With the default window settings, `nodeIntegration` has no effect on loading the Highcharts library. I tested it and it works fine when it's on or off. The problem here is setting `contextIsolation` to `false`. It seems that you lose the context of the Highcharts object then and that's why it throws this error.